# How to specify size for geom_point and geom_line separately and get separate legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

I'm trying to plot igraph network with *ggplot2*. I use `geom_point()` for the vertex and `geom_line()` for the edges. The point size and line width in *ggplot2* are both specified by size. When I specified them separately, I hope to get two separate legends but they turned out to be merged. Below is an example.

```
# an example graph
df <- data.frame(from=letters[c(1, 1, 2:4, 4)], to=letters[c(2, 3, 5:7, 1)])
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=FALSE)

Vname <- V(g)$name
set.seed(100)
V(g)$varVsize <- rnorm(length(Vname))
E(g)$varEwidth <- rnorm(nrow(df))
E(g)$varEcol <- rnorm(nrow(df), 1, 1)

Vcord <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g) # get coordinates for the Vertex
rownames(Vcord) <- V(g)$name 
# 2-column edge list
el <- get.edgelist(g)
el_df <- data.frame(as.data.frame(el), Ewidth=E(g)$varEwidth, Ecol=E(g)$varEcol)
# assigning edge id so that it can be used as group
el_df$id <- 1:nrow(el_df)
## now g_df have each node in the edgelist as a row: first nodesFrom (id=1:145), then nodesTo (id=146:290, i.e.)
el_dfm <- melt(el_df, id=3:5)
xy_s <- data.frame(value = rownames(Vcord),
Vsize=V(g)$varVsize, # add Vetex attribues here: affects size and color 
    x = Vcord[, 1],  
    y = Vcord[, 2])
g_df2 <- merge(el_dfm, xy_s, by = "value")  
# fig 1
ggplot(g_df2, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point(data=g_df2, aes(x, y, size=Vsize), alpha=0.4) +
    geom_line(aes(color=Ecol, group = id)) + 
    geom_text(size = 4, aes(label = value), colour='blue')  
# fig 2: Vsize and Ewidth legend are merged: transparency in geom_line is used so it will not overlap geom_point    
ggplot(g_df2, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point(data=g_df2, aes(x, y, size=Vsize), alpha=0.4) +
    geom_line(aes(color=Ecol, group = id, size=Ewidth), alpha=0.3) + 
    geom_text(size = 4, aes(label = value), colour='blue')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642190/how-to-set-multiple-legends-for-the-same-aesthetic-in-ggplot2) about multiple legends for the same aesthetic?

Comment: Thank you! This is a good try! However, after trying to apply similar trick, I found there is a big difference. The two legends provided in your link are from two different things: colour and size. The situation here is that both legends are from size (size of geom_point and size of geom_line).