# ggplot is trying to interperet the strings inside my color variable as colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

```r
ggplot(data = plot_2022points_ALL, aes(ScoringSystem, Rank)) +
  ggbump::geom_bump(linewidth = 1.5,
                    mapping = aes(group=player_display_name, 
                                  color= I(team_color))) +
  geom_point(aes(group=player_display_name, color=I(team_color2)),
             size=4) +
  geom_text(data = plot_2022points_ALL %>% filter(ScoringSystem == "ENOsysrank"),
            aes(label=player_display_name,
                color=position_group),
            size = 4,
            fontface = "bold",
            nudge_x = -0.2,
            hjust = 1)
```

When I pass this code it returns the error:

```
Error in `geom_text()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error:
! Unknown colour name: QB
```

Everything else I have found online says to just put the color variable inside of `aes()` but I have already done that.
Is this because other geoms use the `I()` function for their color mappings? However, I would expect that the color mappings of other geoms would not affect the others...

Here is an example of what my data looks like:

| position_group | player_display_name | team | points | ScoringSystem | Rank | team_color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QB | Patrick Mahomes | KC | 485.4 | ENOsysrank | 1 | #E31837 |
| TE | Justin Jefferson | MIN | 378.7 | PPR | 6 | #4F2683 |

I tried putting the color aes into the `ggplot()` function and deleting the `color=` inside of the geom aes, but that didn't work.

Edit for clarity: I would like the geom_text to be colored according to `position_group` whereas the other two geoms colored according to the hex values in `team_color`

Comment: Does your code produce the expected output if you remove the `I()`'s? I.e. `color= team_color` instead of `color= I(team_color)`?

Comment: if I remove the `I()`, then it does not register the hex values in the `team_color` column as colors, but rather treats them as text. I want `geom_point` and `geom_bump` to be colored according to the hex values in `team_color`, but `geom_text` to be colored automatically by ggplot according to `position_group`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set multiple legends / scales for the same aesthetic in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642190/how-to-set-multiple-legends-scales-for-the-same-aesthetic-in-ggplot2)

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642190/how-to-set-multiple-legends-scales-for-the-same-aesthetic-in-ggplot2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347147/using-two-scale-colour-gradients-ggplot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ggplot2 to map the color directly from your variable, you need [`scale_color_identity()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_identity.html) and remove the `I()`.

You cannot get an additional, separate color scale with base ggplot2. There are several extension packages which have some variant of this functionality. Here it is with [ggnewscale](https://eliocamp.github.io/ggnewscale/). For more check related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70937627/13210554 and [Using two scale colour gradients ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18347147/13210554)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggnewscale)

d <- data.frame(grp = c("a", "b"),  x = 1:2,  y = 1:2,  col = c("forestgreen", "#4F2683"))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = col), size = 8) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_text(aes(x = x + 0.25, y = y + 0.25, label = grp, color = grp), size = 20) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I would like the geom_text to use the position_group variable for coloring. The team_color variable is used in another geom.