# Apply different colour gradient on same plot and same variable, but different dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, gradient

I am working on a model and I am testing its sensibility. To represent it, I would like to represent on the same plot different results of the model when I change one parameter. But to distinguish my runs, I would like to apply different colour gradients. So far, I tried different methods but it doesn't work. For now, my best results is with this script :

```
plot1<-ggplot(data=datamid, aes(x=mass.mat,y=age.mat,col=Temp.mean, shape = as.factor(Temp.amp)))+
  ggtitle("Mass and age at maturity")+
  geom_path(aes(group=Temp.mean))+
  geom_point(aes(size=as.factor(Temp.amp)))+
  scale_shape_manual(values =c('0.001'=17,
                               '4'=16,
                               '6'=16,
                               '8'=16,
                               '10'=16))+
  scale_size_manual(values = c('0.001'=2,
                               '4'=4,
                               '6'=6,
                               '8'=8,
                               '10'=10))+
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", na.value = NA)+ 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(150,525))+  
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(6,25))+
  ylab(label='Age@maturity (days)')+xlab(label="Mass@maturity (arbitrary)")+
  labs(colour="Mean (°C)", shape="Amplitude (°C)")+
  theme(legend.background  = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))+
  theme_light(base_size = 22)#+ylim(c(20,max(data$mass.mat)))+xlim(c(4,max(data$age.mat)))


plotfinal<-plot1+
  geom_path(data = datahigh, aes(group = Temp.mean)) +
  geom_point(data = datahigh, aes(col = Temp.mean, size=as.factor(Temp.amp))) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "green", high = "yellow", na.value = NA) +
  geom_path(data = datalow, aes(group = Temp.mean)) +
  geom_point(data = datalow, aes(col = Temp.mean, size=as.factor(Temp.amp))) +
  scale_colour_gradient( low = "purple", high = "orange", na.value = NA) +
plotfinal
```

but this is what I get :
[image]

As you can see, with this, the last scale colour gradient is apply on other, but I would like to assign one scale colour gradient for my different data set, but I don't know how.

Comment: ggplot only likes to make one scale per aesthetic. If you want to force a new scale, see the existing solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642190/how-to-set-multiple-legends-scales-for-the-same-aesthetic-in-ggplot2

Comment: + have a look at `{ggnewscale}`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Friede, I tried with the ggnewscale library and it works :

```
plotfinal<-plot1+
new_scale_color()+
geom_path(data = datahigh, aes(group = Temp.mean, col=Temp.mean)) +
geom_point(data = datahigh, aes(col = Temp.mean, size=as.factor(Temp.amp))) +
scale_colour_gradient(low = "green", high = "yellow", na.value = NA) +
new_scale_color()+
geom_path(data = datalow, aes(group = Temp.mean,col=Temp.mean)) +
geom_point(data = datalow, aes(col = Temp.mean, size=as.factor(Temp.amp))) +
scale_colour_gradient( low = "purple", high = "orange", na.value = NA)
```

[image]