# Plotting more than one legend key per aesthetic group in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2

I've been writing an ggplot2-based R package that implements [quantile plots](https://github.com/karchern/ggquantileplot) (a color/hue-based alternative to box plots where darker hues encompass central data points and lighter hues encompass peripheral data points).

[image]

Internally, I've written a `stat` that computes quantiles and a `geom` based on `GeomBoxplot` that plots one crossbar per quantile.

#### Issue

From what I understand about the internals of ggplot2, it is not possible to plot more than one legend key per aesthetic group. What I mean by that is if you use ggplot2 with an aesthetic like `aes(fill = yourVector)` and `yourVector` has 3 distinct levels (let's assume you use `drop = FALSE` so all factor levels are included in the legend), then you'll get 3 keys in legend.

Is there a way to plot more than one key per level? I looked at the `draw_key_*` functions and one could plot more than one legend key by modifying those but I couldn't find a way to inform the function which key (of which group) is currently plotted, so I couldn't modify the coordinates.

The way I solve this right now is with a helper function that adds dummy levels to the vector mapped to the `fill` aesthetic and this way I can get a legend but I don't like this because (a) it modifies the data of the user which is really ugly and (b) I'd like to solve this fully within `ggplot2`.

[image]

Comment: I think you could try `ggdist::stat_interval()` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of that package. Unfortunately It looks as if their interval plot doesn't allow grouped/dodged plots the way that I want them, and it also doesn't look like their stat/geom helps me with my problem.

Comment: THis is a quite common question and there are plenty of threads out there. In the past, I've tried to link as much as I could find to this thread here which has a wiki answer with several possible options. https://stackoverflow.com/q/17642190/7941188

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tjebo, but the post you linked doesn't really address my issue. I'm aware I can hack together a legend using extra external ggplot2 function calls or perhaps from the packages you've linked in the other post, but this is not what I intend. I want to solve this cleanly purely within ggplot2, presumably by writing a new Geom/Stat/whatever.

My question isn't even really about plotting more than 1 legend per aes, but instead about plotting more than one legend KEY per group.

I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: I appreciate your well-intentioned input. It was not my intention to label the packages or their authors 'hacky'.  Yet I'm starting to feel a little bit misheard . I made it clear that I want to solve my problem purely within ggplot2 without external packages. The reason: Ultimately I want to learn how ggplot2 works internally better. I do not want to use these external packages because I do not learn this way.

I did not provide code here  because I already packaged my code but I did link the git repo in my initial post: https://github.com/karchern/ggquantileplot

Comment: Furthermore: I don't think putting a bounty on the link you sent makes sense. My question is not about how to produce more than one legend for the same aesthetic, but instead how to plot more than one key per group.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood you indeed. I think you would get more help if your question would at least contain _some_ code. It's really not easy to help you without you giving us anything, and it's also asked a lot to let us dig through your source code. I know it may sometimes not seem like it, but most of us are busy people with a normal working life and only limited amount of spare time at our hands.

Comment: To be more constructive now: You mentioned you would have created a helper function that modifies the users data which you don't like, but it gives you your desired output. Isn't this something you can do within the compute function in your Stat? This would not actually modify the data, only "under the hood", but would possibly bring your desired output

Comment: @tjebo Moving the helper code into the setup_data/setup_params parts of the Stat allowed me solve my issue :) Thanks a lot!!