# How to use a different color palette in a Ternary plot for separate data being added to the same plot?

Tags: r, plot, ternary

here is my original code that works great.

```
ggmacrem <- ggtern(remnant, aes(x = `tn.g.kg`, y = `P.ppm`, z = `K.ppm`)) +
  stat_density_tern(geom = "polygon", aes(fill = ..level..), bins = 50, 
                    alpha = 0.9) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "PRGn") +
  
  labs(title = "A",
       x = "N",
       y = "P",
       z = "K") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")  # Remove all legends
```

[image: Ternary Plot output]

What I have tried to do is add another set of data to that same plot to show the shift in data from one treatment to another. Below is the example. I would like to make the second set of data a different color and alpha to show the difference. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

If I change the color palette in the second data set it changes the whole color of both datasets.

## Combined  data from ggmacrest with ggmacrem

```
  ggmacrem <- ggmacrem +
  stat_density_tern(data = restoration, geom = "polygon", aes(fill = ..level..),
                    bins = 50, alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "PGRN") +
  labs(title = "B", x = "N", y = "P", z = "K") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")


    print(ggmacrem)
```

[image: Ternary Plot output]

Comment: `new_colour_scale()` from the `ggnewscale` package will most likely solve your issue. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70937627/2530121) for an example.

Comment: It will not let me unpack the ggnewscale package. I am afraid im unqualified to make it load without messing up something else

Comment: I appreciate the help on that, though. Do you know of any other way? Thanks again.

Comment: Adding a package like `ggnewscale` won't mess up anything so no need to worry. Add what you tried and the error message that pops up to your question. When you update your question, say something like "I tried to install ggnewscale but got this error:". It is likely you need something else or your version of R needs updating. Or maybe you're on a computer without admin rights?

Comment: install.packages("ggnewscale")
library(ggnewscale)



# Combine the data from ggmacrest with ggmacrem
ggmacrem <- ggmacrem +
  stat_density_tern(data = restoration, geom = "polygon", aes(fill = ..level..),
                    bins = 50, alpha = 0.1) +
  new_colour_scale() +
  labs(title = "B", x = "N", y = "P", z = "K") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

# Plot ggmacrem with the added data from ggmacrest
print(ggmacrem)

Comment: # Combine the data from ggmacrest with ggmacrem
> ggmacrem <- ggmacrem +
+   stat_density_tern(data = restoration, geom = "polygon", aes(fill = ..level..),
+                     bins = 50, alpha = 0.1) +
+   new_colour_scale() +
+   labs(title = "B", x = "N", y = "P", z = "K") +
+   theme(legend.position = "none")
Error in new_colour_scale() : could not find function "new_colour_scale"

Comment: I had a play around with some toy data and it turns out `ggnewscale` does not work for `ggtern`. The reason is probably because it is not really appropriate to use different colour gradients to represent two datasets with the same relative values. In other words, it makes 'like for like' comparisons highly problematic. A side by side plot is probably a more appropriate way to represent your data. If you need help with this, comment and I will add an answer.